# How to get List Of Connected Users in Google Plus via phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-plus

My project requires me to get the list of connected users to the account.

I saw that i can do it using this
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/connected?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

however, im having problems on how to supply YOUR_API_KEY

I tried this
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

and was able to acquire the oauthtoken but it doesnt appear to be the api_key.
note : obj.idToken is always null so im only able to get the oauthtoken.

if someone could point me in the right direction that would be a great help.

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some mistake in [documentation](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus). You need to use `webApiKey` param instead of `webClientId`. Look at `GooglePlus.java` in your Cordova plugin directory - how your JS params are put to Google Api.